# Create Linked List in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, linked-list

how can I create a linked list in actionScript 3.0? I have a project that I should get some integer numbers from the user and sort them by a tree algorithm for example heap-sort and show the tree in flash, I think I should use linked list to sort the data by tree algorithms.
so anybody know how can I create a linked list which I can insert nodes, delete nodes and pass over the nodes, just like C++ linked list.
Thanks.
SA

Comment: http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/548

Comment: Did you try the term "as3 linked list" in your favorite search engine?

Comment: Although discontinued, I used as3ds (actionscript 3 data structures) quite a lot when I was actionscripting. It's got many useful structures (including linked list). You can still download it from here: http://lab.polygonal.de/?page_id=179

Comment: Are you running into a performance problem using arrays? I couldn't imagine having a dataset in this scenario that an array wouldn't handle efficiently enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use or take as an exmaple [as3Commons linked list implementation](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-collections/asdoc/index.html). They provide very beautiful implementation with very good abstraction layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `mx` package, you could use [mx.utils.LinkedList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/LinkedList.html).

To construct the `LinkedList` you could repeatedly `push` or `unshift` items onto it.

```
var input:Array = getInput();
var myList:LinkedList = new LinkedList();
for each (var o:Object in input) {
    myList.push(o);
}
```

Comment: Weirdly (to me, being used to cons lists), the `tail` attribute of a LinkedList is a LinkedList node. My guess is that this is because AS3 tends to favor mutable data structures.